# Problem with changing font size and font color in e book reader app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have sample code for e book reader for iphone application from github.com named pagecurl demo example. Now it has the animation of page curl effect as I needed for my app, but I also want is about how to change the color and size of font, if someone can provide me some link or how to proceed further or some sample code it would be a great help.

Regards,
Abhi

Comment: To help you, we'll need, at the very least, the link to said github project. To make it easier for us, you should supply some code, specially the part where the text is displayed.

Comment: If you're willing to wait until around September, you might find that this will become much easier... I'm not sure I can say much more than that due to Apple's NDA around new features in iOS...